# Ng-repeat showing incorrectly like a waterfall

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm having a problem with ng-repeat: it's showing content like a waterfall. I don't think it has to do with my css because it's the same problem in plunker 
Image: http://i59.tinypic.com/kah6qf.png

Code:

```
       <div class="panel panel-primary">
  <div class="panel-heading">
     <h3 class="panel-title">Products</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
     <ul>
        <li class="product-item" ng-repeat="product in products">
           <div class="product-img">
              <img src="{{product.productPic}}" alt="{{product.name}}" />
           </div>
           <div class="product-name-price">
              <p>{{product.name}} <span class="price">{{product.price}}</span>
              </p>
           </div>
        </li>
     </ul>
  </div>
```

[Here's a Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/BuhkWT3QPxRENYyOF9rV)

Thanks

Comment: because I don't want it that way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It actually is your CSS. Take out the float on the .product-img div.

Answer (score 2):

Basic CSS issue, I would also float the list item not the image - [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/JSvpYhzpU7XUPJwa8qvW?p=preview)

```
.product-item {
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  float: left;
  width:25%;
}
.product-img {
  margin: 5px;
}
```